# Delay when using Google Calendar API with Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-calendar-api, python-3.6

Per the example script on the page [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python)

I've noticed that in python 2.7.14 the example runs quickly. When I changed to python 3.6.4 (to ensure compatibility with a script I am making) there is about a 21 second slowdown with the line in question:

```
service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
```

However, if I disable ipv6 on my network interface, it returns to processing more quickly. Can anyone explain this issue, and what I can do to run more efficiently while not having to interfere with ipv6 functionality?